# Sequelize Typescript Associations without Foreign Key - is it possible?

Tags: join, sequelize.js, associations, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to define a pair of `@HasMany / @BelongsTo` association without foreign key, for use with custom `include / join on` conditions.

But I still got the error: `Foreign key for {Model1} is missing on {Model2}`, even though I used the option: `constraints: false`.

Not sure if this is supported with Sequelize and `sequelize-typescript` ?

[Ref. GitHub issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript/issues/1544)

### Example Code

***AnonymousQuestionModel.ts***

```
export interface AnonymousQuestionAttributes {
    // ...
}

@Table
export class AnonymousQuestionModel
  extends Model<AnonymousQuestionAttributes>
  implements AnonymousQuestionAttributes {
    @AutoIncrement
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column({ type: DataType.BIGINT })
    id!: number

   @Column
   email!: string

   @Column
   subject!: string

    @Column
    description!: string

    @BelongsTo(() => QuestionModel, { constraints: false, foreignKeyConstraint: false })
    maybeUserQuestion?: QuestionAttributes | null
}

export interface QuestionAttributes extends Omit<AnonymousQuestionAttributes, 'email'> {
    user: UserAttributes
}
```

***QuestionModel.ts***

```
@Table
export class QuestionModel extends Model<QuestionAttributes> implements QuestionAttributes {
    @AutoIncrement
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column({ type: DataType.BIGINT })
    id!: number

   @Column
   subject!: string

    @Column
    description!: string

    @ForeignKey(() => UserModel)
    userId!: number

    @BelongsTo(() => UserModel)
    user!: UserAttributes

    @HasMany(() => AnonymousQuestionModel, { constraints: false, foreignKeyConstraint: false })
    maybeDuplicateQuestions: AnonymousQuestionAttributes[] = []
}
```

***QuestionsService.ts***

```
export class QuestionService {
  constructor(protected readonly questionModel: ModelStatic<QuestionModel>) {
  }

  findAllWithDuplicates(opts: FindOptions<QuestionAttributes>) {
    return this.questionModel.findAll({
        ...opts,
        include: [
            {
                association: 'user',
            },
            {
                association: 'maybeDuplicateQuestions',
                on: {
                   [Op.and]: [
                        Sequelize.where(
                           Sequelize.col('QuestionModel.user.email'),
                           Op.eq,
                           Sequelize.col('maybeDuplicateQuestions.email')
                    ),
                    Sequelize.where(
                        Sequelize.col('QuestionModel.subject'),
                        Op.eq,
                        Sequelize.col('maybeDuplicateQuestions.subject')
                    ),
                }
            },
        ],
        order: [
            [Sequelize.col('QuestionModel.id'), 'desc'],
            [Sequelize.col('maybeDuplicateQuestions.id'), 'desc'],
        ],
    })
  }
}
```